10th Anniversary of Hinduism SE!
In June Hinduism SE will turn 10 years old. Congratulations on asking, answering, voting, and building this community for a whole decade!
Whenever a Stack Exchange site turns 10 we like to celebrate by encouraging users to reflect on their experiences here.
How did you first discover the site? Do you have a favorite question or answer that helped you solve a problem? Any funny anecdotes or other insights on your time here, that you would like to share? We want to hear it all!

Can't believe it's been 10 years already! Congratulations and thanks to each fellow users who have helped in sharing, asking, answering knowledge throughout these many years. Keep up the spirit !!

Yay! I've only been a member of this site for a year or so, but this is such a useful site: Lots of amazing questions have been asked, and even more wonderful answers have been posted. From queries that have helped individuals (like reference-request questions that have turned up the scriptural citation to long-ago-heard slokas) to queries that have prompted answers that millions must have been wondering about (like what does om signify), so much knowledge has been shared on this site.
Unfortunately, a lot of the original users have disappeared, as we discussed in chat recently, the quality of questions and answers have gone down a bit, and review-participation has become lower. I hope that this milestone will help remind people how enlightening and fulfilling this site is.
Here's to ten more years of excellent questions and answers!

Nice. Glad to find that Hinduism.SE is entering into another decade!
We have one post here on What brought you here and what topics you find interesting where one can write a brief about him/her.
Talking about useful/favorite posts, we used to run such a series earlier where some interested users used to talk about their favorites posts.
We worked a lot on making/updating the help-center pages, FAQs and policies to draw quality posts, guiding users to avoid things that deviates/degrades the site objective and efforts towards the site graduation also. We celebrated the moment when Hinduism.SE lose the beta label and graduated! Although this community has become a self-governing site with the efforts of all past and present knowledgeable users and (has become) a repository of reliable threads on topics related to Hinduism across the internet. However sustaining the quality of posts and interests of users sounds still challenging!
It is not applicable to few veteran users only but to most of users including me! We need something here to consistently encourage the established users. Otherwise after every some interval of time, the site will be getting majority of posts/answers from new and inexperience users only which would create difficulty in maintaining the site quality and in guiding the newcomers. Similar happening is pointed out by user CDR in his answer. (This prediction may not be perfect as due to my lesser activities on the site these days, I might not be aware about the exact conditions and my co-modes can correct me).
How about encouraging users to read more fundamental scriptures/texts so as to increase the quality of knowledge (through self-development) and of posts (through users contribution)? We can have a separate meta post for this discussion.
Again, I would like to thank to the Stack Exchange CM/Staff to congratulate us through this post (and to make our meta-site bit active! Haha).
Yes, we have many good number of favorite posts, the list is long and users are encourage to posts their favorite posts :)
